# margin:0 auto is not working in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float, margin

margin:0 auto is not working in internet explorer.It is working well in firefox.

Please check the site http://jobslanda.com/

```
#Body{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 23px 20px 10px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color:#ffffff;   
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FBF8F4;
    border: medium none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Sincerely,

Sunil

Comment: Its working fine on IE7+ I have checked be sure you are not loading this in quirks mode. do one thins in go in IE press f12 and see in which mode your site opens

Comment: So, are you referring to the offset in the bottom block, or something else? EDIT: I see that none of the blocks are centered in the white area. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to your second rule, `#wrapper`. Auto margins only work when the element has a known width; `#wrapper` is `width:auto` at the moment, so there is no left-over margin to divvy up.

Comment: I have changed the width and height of wrapper to 100%. But still the problem exists.